# MS Access driver issue

Tags: .net, windows, vba, ms-access

I created a windows Forms application which is using access 2010 database (ODBC). After I created installer package and published the application, the user is not able to retrieve the data in the application from the access database. MS office is not installed in the user's system. Is there a way to use MS Access database in the application without he need for the user to have MS Office?

Comment: Yes, just use ADO.net You don't need MS Access at all: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [MS Access Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) on the client pc.

```
The Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime enables you to distribute Access 2010 applications 
to users who do not have the full version of Access 2010 installed on their computers.
```

You may distribute the runtime freely.

Comment: The [Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) is preferred over the Access runtime if users only have to connect to Access through an external application.